# wix bootstrapper causes msi to fail

Tags: wix

I've finally gotten Wix to build an msi, that is all working fine now, when run alone. But when, on my own machine, I try to wrap it in a bootstrapper I get an error that c:\cpp\setup.msi can't be found. And it comes from my .msi installer !? It does not do that on my laptop, it works there. But it is concerning. I'm so close to having a package I can use...

Looks like:
[image]
The source for my bootstrapper.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension"
  xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <!--https://gist.github.com/nathancorvussolis/6852ba282647aeb0c5c00e742e28eb48-->
  <Bundle
    Name="Reserve Analyst"
    Version="5.4.10"
    Manufacturer="Highlands Electronics"
    Copyright="© 2019 Highlands Electronics"
    AboutUrl="https://reserveanalyst.com/"
    UpgradeCode="{54127D63-F422-4EBD-A6F5-902BF07CB089}"
    Condition="VersionNT >= v5.1">

    <BootstrapperApplicationRef
      Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
        ShowVersion="yes"
       LicenseFile="C:\cpp\ReserveAnalyst_142\Setup\Bootstrapper\logo.rtf"
        LogoFile="C:\cpp\ReserveAnalyst_142\WixSetup\images\gyro.png"
        LogoSideFile="C:\cpp\ReserveAnalyst_142\WixSetup\images\gyro.png"
        SuppressOptionsUI="no" />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>

    <!-- Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) minimum runtime msi package version -->
    <util:ProductSearch
      Id="VCRedist2015x86"
      Result="version"
      Variable="VCRedist2015x86"
      UpgradeCode="65E5BD06-6392-3027-8C26-853107D3CF1A"
      Condition="VersionNT" />

    <!-- Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable version -->
    <Variable Name="VCRedist2015" Type="version" Value="14.0.24215" />

    <Chain>

      <!-- Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (x86) -->
      <ExePackage
        Id="vc_redist.x86.exe"
        Name="vc_redist.x86.14.0.24215.1.exe"
        DisplayName="Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (x86) - 14.0.24215"
        Cache="no"
        Compressed="no"
        PerMachine="yes"
        Permanent="yes"
        InstallCondition="VersionNT"
        DetectCondition="VCRedist2015x86 >= VCRedist2015"
        DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/6/A/A/6AA4EDFF-645B-48C5-81CC-ED5963AEAD48/vc_redist.x86.exe"
        InstallCommand="/install /quiet /norestart"
        RepairCommand="/repair /quiet /norestart"
        UninstallCommand="/uninstall /quiet /norestart" >
        <RemotePayload
          ProductName="Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3 (x86)"
          Version="14.0.24215.1"
          Description="https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53840"
          CertificatePublicKey="371DD003A37769487A2A89A5A9DDB3026451B906"
          CertificateThumbprint="98ED99A67886D020C564923B7DF25E9AC019DF26"
          Hash="72211BD2E7DFC91EA7C8FAC549C49C0543BA791B"
          Size="14456872" />
      </ExePackage>

      <RollbackBoundary />
      <!-- ReserveAnalyst.msi -->
      <MsiPackage
        Id="X86"
        DisplayName="Reserve Analyst Software"
        DisplayInternalUI="yes"
        ForcePerMachine="yes"
        Compressed="yes"
        SourceFile="C:\cpp\ReserveAnalyst_142\wix\bin\Release\ReserveAnalyst.msi"
        InstallCondition="VersionNT"/>

    </Chain>
  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

There is more, but one question at a time. I take it I can't do much with the Wix bootstrapper, like get rid of the license page. My attempt to change the logo does not work. I just want it to install the prerequisite and I have the license in my .msi

The [work I've done](https://github.com/lakeweb/WixFarm) so far. I may have reinvented Wix wheels but it helped me to understand Wix better.

Thanks, Dan.

Comment: Look at the log files: https://support.firegiant.com/hc/en-us/articles/230912407-Create-a-log-file-

Comment: Hi @Bob Arnson I had looked at it but could make no sense. It so happens that the bootstrapper calls the .msi with logging. It told me in its falure log where the big log was, ../user/appdata/local/temp. I've [pasted](https://pastebin.com/VUxZx84g) from about line 3200 where it starts to fail. There is no setup.msi in my stuff, much less the path c:\cpp\setup.msi At least, as best as I can tell. Thanks, Dan.